SSH login to Windows 10 not possible with a admin account
I am trying to establish an SSH connection from a VirtualBox Ubuntu2204 guest to Windows 10 host via ssh using public key. I can do it when I use a non-admin account, but it fails with an admin account.
Can somebody give me a hint to the solution, as I have given admin rights to my normal account and can still use it for SSH? 

ACLs:

administrators_authorized_keys:
Verzeichnis: C:\ProgramData\ssh

  Path                           Owner                        Access
  ----                           -----                        ------
  administrators_authorized_keys VORDEFINIERT\Administratoren NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl...



Client .ssh/id_rsa:
xubuntu@xubuntu2204:~/.ssh$ getfacl id_rsa
# file: id_rsa
# owner: xubuntu
# group: xubuntu
user::rw-
group::---
other::---





Configs:

Server sshd_config:
PermitRootLogin yes
#AllowUsers AdminHIJ
StrictModes no

PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

ClientAliveInterval 3000

Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe

Match Group administrators
  AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys



Client ssh_config
Host *
  ServerAliveInterval 20
  TCPKeepAlive no





Logs:

Server:
(base) PS C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH> .\sshd.exe -d
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:TGAP/tbzl8vIE64yd37DdC9I2IoC8J+MpIKtKaytLHs
debug1: private host key #1: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:nLrIlMEdU9YNp7uCUHdUDL6z6+ysXalgGZ+53v4aTuQ
debug1: private host key #2: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:eFn4JnkBpBhJ80dj91xKcyYPSM675W9sWCqglMyvkW0
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\sshd.exe'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
Connection from 192.168.50.9 port 41988 on 192.168.50.222 port 22
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user adminhij service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: get_user_token - unable to generate user token for adminhij as i am not running as system
ga_init, unable to resolve user adminhij
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 71992



Client:
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -v  adminhij@192.168.50.222 
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.50.222 [192.168.50.222] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/xubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/xubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.50.222:22 as 'adminhij'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/xubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:eFn4JnkBpBhJ80dj91xKcyYPSM675W9sWCqglMyvkW0
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/xubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '192.168.50.222' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/xubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/xubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:8vTjqYAkpcCEsaRFhBod4YKJLwYj8OPze7UJ2DvJZPk explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
Connection reset by 192.168.50.222 port 22



update
Sorry, but I disagree that my question is a duplicate of logging-into-windows-10-openssh-server-with-administrator-account-and-public-key. This post is about the fact that it is possible to log in via password for a certain account, but not with a public key. My post is about the fact that login is not possible with a certain admin account, but is possible with another one.
The problem account definitely exists under Windows:
(base) PS C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH> Get-LocalUser

Name Enabled Description
---- ------- -----------
AdminHIJ True
....
....

If I use a non-existent account I'm still prompted for a password.
xubuntu@xubuntu2204:~/ansible-tango$ ssh FAKEUSER@192.168.50.222 
FAKEUSER@192.168.50.222's password: 

When I use my problem account AdminHIJ, I get connection reset immediately.
xubuntu@xubuntu2204:~/ansible-tango$ ssh AdminHIJ@192.168.50.222 
Connection reset by 192.168.50.222 port 22

Even if my problem is solved after a lot of trial and error, after amount of time invested it would be nice at least to understand the cause.

Wby are you not using user specific keys? Provide the verbose logs from the server and client at the time of the attempt to connect. Provide the full server configuration file. Provide the ACL for the keys on the client and server.

@music2myear: Thanks for the hint, I have read the post. Unfortunately it doesnt help. When I try to log in with a password, the correct password for adminxyz is rejected. For the notadmin it is accepted.

Dear @Ramhound, i have added information You asked for.

You didn’t provide everything I asked for but it doesn’t matter since the duplicate answers your question. However, your attempting to connect as a user, that doesn’t seem to exist on the Windows installation.

What language packs have you installed on Windows? The name of the user group must match exactly to the same of the name of the user Administrators user group

I am using a German version of Windows, none futher LP are installed. The problem account is a member of Administratoren.
As described in the update, the user is present in Winsows. But the behaviour at ssh connect is strange. A connection with this account is immediately reseted.

So why does your OpenSSH configuration have Administrator instead of Administratoren? The user group match spelling is exact. This is a well documented “problem”.

“unable to resolve user adminhij” - Means the user your attempting to connect as does not exist on the server

Change the following:
Match Group administrators
  AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys


To the following:
Match Group Administratorens
  AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys

Additionally make sure that the key being used can only be accessed by the Administratorens user group. If for some reason this still doesn’t work, verify the exact spelling of the Administrators user group, for the primary system locale.

This does not appear to be the cause.
I have created a new administrator account: testadmin2. I have not created .ssh/authorised_keys for it. The SSH connection works for both: Match Group administrators and Match Group Administratoren.  When I comment these lines, I am asked for the password as I would espect.

Post the properties (user groups) of both users.

Both users belongs to Administratoren, Benutzer, docker-users, Remotedesktopbenutzer
